# Simulate a click() programmatically on a Div

Tags: dart, dart-html

I'm trying to fire an event programmatically. My problem is that I have two SVG on two DIVs and I want to be able to change the border of the DIV I have clicked. To do that I thought to pass the DIV inside my classes and then trigger a click on it once I click on anything. (if there is a better way, please tell me)

I have the following code:

```dart
div = querySelector(divName);
svgElement = new svg.SvgSvgElement();
div.append(svgElement);
div.onClick.listen(_setBorders(1));
```

later I pass the svgElement to another class

```dart
ell.show(svgElement);
```

where show is

```dart
show(svg.SvgElement element) {
  if (element.parent is DivElement){
    _parentDiv= element.parent as DivElement;
    element.children.add(_group);  
  }
}
```

_parentDiv is of course a DivElement, which I use for an internal onClick()

```dart
_onClick(MouseEvent e) {
  window.console.info("onClick Ell");
  _parentDiv.click();
}
```

I'm expecting to see the _setBorders(1); I defined with the main div, but it doesn't work. The weird thing is that when I check with the debugger set to the _parentDiv.click() I see that _parentDiv has the event correctly set.
I suppose click() doesn't work as I expected. Any Idea?

Comment: Don't you want `div.onClick.listen((_) => _setBorders(1));` ? If not could you paste the `_setBorders` method ?

Comment: @Alexandre I might have done a copy mistake, but I thought that what I've written up here shouldn't have worked. What is the difference?

Comment: `listen` takes a Function in parameter. You don't paste the content of your `_setBorders` function but I expect from its name that the call of `_setBorders(1)` doesn't return a Function but rather `void` or `null` or `nothing`. If you want that `_setBorders(1)` is called on click events you have to use `div.onClick.listen((_) => _setBorders(1))`.

Comment: Why the wrong version doesn't give an exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want that `_setBorders(1)` is called on click events you have to use :

```dart
div.onClick.listen((_) => _setBorders(1));
```

Comment: Thanks. I did indeed forgot the first part. I wonder why I didn't get an alert.